# Opening a cv2 videocapture canvas on top of Tkinter main canvas and closing it

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I have a `MainWindow` gui of 800x480 size with Python Tkinter. The gui has a `create_image` background and two `create_window=button` buttons.

One of the buttons launches an Opencv4 `CamStream` canvas deleting the `MainWindow` canvas. After the user clicks mouse 1 anywhere on the video, the video canvas gets destroyed and video device is released.

My problem is "returning" back to the original canvas. The original canvas `MainWindow` is defined in the main program and `CamStream` is imported. When I try to call `MainWindow` inside a `CamStream` method, I get an error saying `MainWindow` is not defined (because im calling it inside an imported class method?).

Maybe there is a better way of doing this? I thought imported code is still ran in the main program and therefore main program classes would be known to it.

Simplified main program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import cv2
from videocapture import CamStream

root = tk.Tk()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=800, height=480)
        self.canvas.pack()

        camButton = tk.Button(window, text = 'camera', command = lambda: self.canvas.destroy() | CamStream(window))
        self.canvas.create_window(300,235, window=camButton, anchor = 'center')

MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Simplified imported `videocapture` code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CamStream:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=800, height=480)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # And other stuff

    def close_video(self, event):
        if MyVideoCapture().vid.isOpened:
            self.vid.vid.release()
            self.canvas.destroy()
            MainWindow(root)          #####Problem creating main canvas  ######
```

Comment: The code you wrote can be a lot better and more simpler. I think you want to open videocam from module opencv to a Tkinter `Canvas` and close it with a click of a `Button` on the video playing... if yes then it can be simpler than this. Also it is a bit confusing in telling which version of opencv you are using as you mentioned _"cv2"_ in the title but you're talking about _"Opencv4"_. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56170985/edit) your post to correct it.

Comment: Read about [Tkinter.Wm.iconify-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.iconify-method) instead of `.destroy()`.

Comment: Saad: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do. I think it is opencv4 but the module is named cv2.

Comment: How you import opencv? like `import cv2`

Comment: yes that is how I import it. Maybe I should include the videocapture file code in the main program

Comment: Yes add necessary details to your post.

Comment: In *videocapture.py* the `MainWindow` is unknown as you haven't imported main file which contains `MainWindow` class. But if you do then I don't get the point of importing both files to each other.

Comment: I changed the code and decided to make only one program that includes both classes. Importing `videocapture` was mainly because I wanted to try how importing works...